# Perfecting a (pid) control system using matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, genetic-algorithm

We have a machine with temperature regulation with which I'm not happy. I'd like to improve the control algorithm to fit better to the machine scenarios.

I've written a simulation system in C# that closely simulates the machine behaviour and benchmarks the control loop parameters, and I'd like to use a learning / minimization algorithm to find the best parameters for each scenario.

The simulator gets 4 parameters - 3 PID parameters, and a PID threshold under which the PID doesn't react. There might be more parameters in the future.
The simulator returns a numeral saying how well the PID performed. A benchmark (for now - higher is better).

The Matlab part runs the C# application with different parameters and should try to find the best parameters according to the returned grade.

Questions:

1. Which minimization algorithm should I use? Should using GA do the trick?
2. (Might be a different question entirely) Is there a way of running the algorithm so it'll run the benchmark applications in parallel?
3. The PID parameters are integers, and Matlab tends to work with doubles. The chosen algorithm should be able to restrict itself to certain accuracy.

Working with ga, this line should start the process:

```
problem.fitnessfcn = @fitness_fcn;
problem.nvars = 4;
problem.intcon = [1,2,3,4];
problem.solver = 'ga';
problem.options = gaoptimset(@ga);
[x fval] = ga(problem)
```

And this is the fitness function:

```
function [ val ] = fitness_fcn( k )

app = '"c:\path\to\sim.exe"';

kp = k(1);
ki = k(2);
kd = k(3);
pidTh = k(4);

command = sprintf('%s %f %f %f %f', app, kp, ki, kd, pidTh);
[status, res] = system(command);

val = str2double(res);

end
```

This kinda works, but I'm not getting any good numbers

Apologies in advance if this should go into EE stack exchange

Comment: The PID control constants shouldn't have to be limited to integers.  They can be floating point numbers too.  Also, have you considered using the Ziegler-Nichols criteria to get your initial PID parameters?  These give you a good start, and you tweak the parameters slightly from this point to get the proper parameters.  Also, what is the rise time and settling time criteria you want to meet? Percent Overshoot?  PID controller design requires that you have certain criteria set out that you want to meet before you even start optimizing.

Comment: The PID integer limit is from the target PLC PID implementation. I haven't considered Ziegler-Nichols - I'll check that out.
The "normal" PID parameters (settling time, overshoot, etc) aren't as important for me as the energy efficiency of the system (how much time does the heating work), so I'm ignoring them for now. Later we'll take them into consideration. That is what the C# simulation tests